# Nav-Bar colocando items dentro do botão

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Comecei a estudar Bootstrap e estou seguindo um passo a passo da [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_me.asp), os itens da nav-bar estão entrando dentro do botão, isso é o esperado quando a página for redimensionada, mas o problema é que ela não está redimensionada e os itens estão entrando dentro do botão. O código é o mesmo da página e simplesmente não funciona..

Código:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Me</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar"></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">QUEM</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">O QUE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ONDE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Links CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
crossorigin="anonymous">
// esse é um onde só tem cores, os códigos também sairam da página da W3CD
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara está funcionando normal. Logo de cara aí no seu código já pude ver que vc fechou a `div` **collapse navbar-collapse**. E outro problema é que vc está seguindo um tutorial que é da versão **3.3.7** e vc está utilizando a versão **4.1.3**, existem diferenças entre as versões. Se vc que aprender com a última versão, procure um tutorial com aquela versão, senão pode ocasionar problemas.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">WHO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WHAT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">WHERE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment:      